# C#: How to effectively filter (hide) ListView Items while in virtual mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

C#: How to effectively filter (hide) ListView Items while in virtual mode?

I am looking for a way to filter (hide/show) items in ListView in Virtual Mode. I have my items cached in an array of listview items, how could I effectively make it so only specific listview items are displayed when pressing a filter-button, and then all of them back when pressing a not-filter button?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to map your list of visible rows, so that when RetrieveVirtualItem requests an item, it requests into your filtered list that only contains visible items.

If you're using CacheVirtualItems to store ListViewItems, you'll need to update that cache when the filtering is applied, removing all non-visible rows. You may want to just clear the cache at that point to reduce complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I did this on my project by adding a property FilterResult to the Objects i was showing in the ListView. Then in the item template used for the ListView, i put a DataTrigger on FilterResult, with a Setter on Visibility, something like :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterResult}" Value="False">
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Then when the user change the filter, i just go through the collection Shown, update each FilterResult (which is a PropertyChanged Notifying property) and voila ! :=)

Another solution, still using the FilterResult flag, would be to create a NotifyingCollection hooked onto your main Collection, that exposes only the items having FilterResult as true. Hence you have to manage CollectionChanged events if one item switch value of FilterResult...